# Hex into EBCDIC

Tags: java, string, hex, converters, ebcdic

I have a GUI where i try to convert a EBCDIC String into Hexadecimal, but it will not work :/

```
ebcdichex.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output6.setText("");
            String hexadecimal3 = input4.getText().replace("\n", "");
            byte[] chars2;

            try {
                chars2 = hexadecimal3.getBytes("IBM-273");
                StringBuilder hexa2 = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0;i<chars2.length;i++){
                    byte[] b = {(byte) Integer.parseInt(chars2.toString(),16)};     
                    hexa2.append(b);
                }
                output6.append(hexa2.toString());
            }
         catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    });
```

Example input:

```
f1f2f3f4
```

translated:

```
1234
```

It just throws this Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[B@147c5fc"
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `chars2.toString()`? A `byte[]` array doesn't override `toString()`; it just inherits it from class `Object`.

Comment: Consider asking the question you actually want to ask.  You are not attempting to convert EBCDIC to Hex, you are converting EBCDIC to ASCII.

Comment: Oh ok, but i really want to convert it into Hex :O

Comment: Consider adding an "expected output" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line looks suspicious:

```
byte[] b = {(byte) Integer.parseInt(chars2.toString(),16)};
```

Assuming that you have your EBCDIC in byte[] array, you can use method to present it as HEX -> for instance from this answer: [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

EDIT:

Are you sure you are using the correct encoding name for EBCDIC? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html
states Cp273

EDIT#2:
Ok, now I got what you want. Here's a sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Conversion
{
    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String hexadecimal3 = "f1f2f3f4";
        byte[] ebcdic = hexStringToByteArray(hexadecimal3);
        System.out.println(  new String(ebcdic, "Cp273") ); // prints 1234
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.... I read the Comment, but i dont get it how it solved my problem :/ Could you explain it to me?

Comment: yeah it is the right one because it contains letter that only exist in germany.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From a hex-digits string you want to get the readable characters, interpreting the hex string as EBCDIC-encoded.

In your code, with `chars2 = hexadecimal3.getBytes("IBM-273");` you create a byte sequence that encodes the hex digits from `hexadecimal3` one by one to EBCDIC. Later you try to convert that EBCDIC byte sequence back to a String `chars2.toString()`, not telling Java that it's EBCDIC, and try to parse that as hexadecimal.

You should do:

- Parse all the 2-character substrings from the input individually as hex numbers and store the results as byte array `bytes`.
- Create the result as `new String(bytes, "IBM-273")`

And a style recommendation:

extract the logic into a method like `String stringFromEbcdicHex(String ebcdicHexDigits)`.

EDIT:

To parse the 2-character substrings, you can do something like:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[ebcdicHexDigits.length/2];
for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(ebcdicHexDigits.substring(2*i, 2*i+2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. How can i parse the 2-character substrings?